Running "Ephemeral Node"
Is there a way to run an "ephemeral" node for Solana? Meaning I want to subscribe to events on chain like logsSubscribe but without storing all history since I don't have the hardware requirements. I just want an RPC node that can store recent events for example send me all transactions of an account as they are broadcasted. I found this but not sure what it actually does since its not FOSS yet.

Unfortunately, it isn't really possible at the protocol layer yet, since a call like logsSubscribe requires a full VM and account state. There may be other services that provide this, but it would all be built on top of Geyser / RPC on a full validator.
